# Twitter bootstrap3: HTML5, non-cross-domain iframe scale width and height

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know this has been asked many times before, but please read on.

In [bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/), I am trying to get an iframe to fill out a div.

I have scoured the internet and SO extensively, and tried every single thing I have come across with no luck.

Here is the scoop:

1. I need to load an html-page in a narrow div ID. It is not cross-domain; I have control over both.
2. I need to be able to style the content inside the iframe. Can I do that from "master" page (i.e the target page), or do I need to do that in the "incoming page", i.e. the iframe content html?
3. the iframe must be flexible: the height and width (width because of responsive design) need to expand according to content.

I am desperate, and wondering if Bootstrap3 is overriding something?

I have tried a desperate amount of css alteration in combination with the long list of css and js-solutions listed below.

Here are a bunch of things (not all) I have tried :-S

- [Twitter Bootstrap iFrame usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307518/twitter-bootstrap-iframe-usage)
- [What's the correct way to size an iframe in a Twitter bootstrap fluid layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536015/whats-the-correct-way-to-size-an-iframe-in-a-twitter-bootstrap-fluid-layout)
- http://bootply.com/search?kw=iframe
- [Set iframe content height to auto resize dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024574/get-and-set-iframe-content-height-auto-resize-dynamically-easy-solution-expandin)
- [Make Iframe to fit 100% of container's remaining height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325273/make-iframe-to-fit-100-of-containers-remaining-height)
- [cross-domain iframe resizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606920/cross-domain-iframe-resizer/6940531#6940531)
- [to fit iframe to its content height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724499/to-fit-iframe-to-its-content-height)

Comment: You say 'you have control of the domain' but are they the *exact* same domain? even down to the protocol? If not, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: I would say yes. This _might_ change some point in the future, but for now they are the same.

Answer (score 4):

Some options:

1: Try making the iframe responsive.  iframes can't automagically expand, so you're going to have to decide on a good height, or use JavaScript.  For width, bootstrap has you mostly covered.  You do need to make a div around the iframe to respond for it.  Then set the iframe's width css to 100%.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
             <h1>I'm the left column</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <iframe style="width: 100%;" src="http://..." height="200px"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qgxa9/2/embedded/result/)

2: Don't use an iframe.  If it's on the same origin, use a function like [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
$('#targetlocation').load('/usually_in_an_iframe.html #main_element');
```

3: a combination of #1 and that fit a frame to its height question you linked to

Comment: Thank you, I will fiddle away at this; and for the record; Jquery is entirely acceptable.

Comment: Just an update: i can use load() with the following oddities: it will not work locally on Chrome, but works in FF. If uploaded to server, it works in Chrome. I have no problem getting the iFrame to adjust to width; height is still a major problem.

Comment: It's a security feature; you can't query for files with file urls.  If you run a server, though, it will work.  If you're using load, height shouldn't be a problem because there's no iframes.

Comment: Yes, I gathered that. I treat them as two separate things at the moment. The load works fine, iframe hight a nightmare. Not giving up, though, and I will report back in case this might be useful for others in the future.

Comment: Update: I get the iframe to adjust to height with the help of the following code: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/how_to_adjust_an_iframe_elements_height_to_fit_its_content/ This will make the iframe adjust to 100% height when the _whole_ page loads. The next problem though, is that I cannot get hight adjustment when the _content_ of the iframe changes. Imagine: iframe loads fine. Inside the iframe is a collapse, and when I click on it to "drop down" collapse, I get the scrollbars. :-( Not giving up..

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 3.2 has released a handy responsive iframe class:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

i.e:

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```